# How to take result value of a jQuery script into a C# code in the same razor page in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

I have used jQuery to find selected row index of a table. I need to use the result in C# code in the same razor page (Not in controller). I tried to use Ajax but I don't know what url I have to use. Please help me.

```
<script>
    var rowIndex;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#pmElectrical').on("click", "tbody tr", function(){
            rowIndex = $(this).index();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: ????
                data: {_pmId: rowIndex},
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(){
                    alert(rowIndex);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: your question is not clear. Kindly explain what you are looking for, Also if you want to read the selected row data.

Comment: Hi @Fardin, it seems you do not know razor pages routing. 1. Could you please share your  current page `.cs` file? 2. Did your current page define any route template on `@page` directive? 3. What is your current page locate? A project structure will be helpful. Please share more details with us.

Comment: I shared a working demo and detailed explanation for routing. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you do not know the routing in razor pages. Here are several scenarios about routing.

Razor pages uses `OnGet` and `OnPost` to deal with the Http Get and Post request. If you need another Get or Post method in current PageModel, you need define the method name like: **OnGet**HandlerName or **OnPost**HandlerName.

### How URLs are matched

By default, the route templates are generated by taking the virtual path of each content page and then removing the root folder name(**Pages foler**) from the start and the file extension from the end.

That is to say the route should be: `/FolderName/PageName`. If contains handler, it should be: `/FolderName/PageName?handler=HandlerName`.

### For example:

Create a folder named `Test` in `Pages` folder. Then create an `Create.cshtml`. Location is:`/Pages/Test/Create.cshtml`.

[image]

This page default url should be: `Test/Create`. If in `Create.cshtml.cs` contains `OnGetDisplay`/`OnPostDisplay` handler and you need call this handler, the url should be:`/Test/Create?handler=Display`.

**Notes:**

One important thing you need know when your page is named `Index.cshtml`. Both of the following templates can match `Index.cshtml`:

```
"FolderName"          
"FolderName/Index"
```

Both of these routes will be mapped to the same virtual path: `/<root>/FolderName/Index.cshtml`.

This also indicates another thing, if you create a `Test.cshtml` page directly in root(`Pages` folder), the url is also:`/Test`. This will cause AmbiguousActionException. Please take care.

---

### Route Templates

If you define Route Templates, Route Data parameters are defined in a Route Template as part of the `@page` directive in the `.cshtml` file.

```
@page "{title}"
```

The template created for this route is `/FolderName/PageName/TitleName`(e.g. `/Test/Create/aaa`).

---

### How to use Ajax in Razor Pages

Razor Pages enable anti-forgery token validation by default, so you need add this token to header in ajax.

If you use form in Razor Pages, it will default generate an input with token. If not, you need add `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` manually.

---

### A whole working demo you could follow:

Page(Create.cshtml locates in `/Pages/Test` folder):

```
@page
@model WebApplication1.Pages.Test.CreateModel
@{
}

<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <td>aa</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>bb</td>
        <td>15</td>
    </tr>
</table>
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        var rowIndex;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('tr').click(function () {
                rowIndex = $("tr").index(this);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Test/Create",
                    data: { _pmId: rowIndex },
                    headers: {
                        RequestVerificationToken:
                            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                    },
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function () {
                        alert(rowIndex);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

PageModel:

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {
    }
    public void OnPost(int _pmId)
    {

    }
}
```

**Update:**

If you use ASP.NET Core MVC, the url should be:`/ControllerName/ActionName`.

Comment: Do I need to write your pagemodel code in my ViewModel or do I need to write it in the Controller?

Comment: Not sure if your razor pages need display anything by OnGet method. But the OnPost method should keep same as mine with parameter `_pmId`. `or do I need to write it in the Controller` in your question you said you use razor page not controller. Please confirm your project if it is a mvc project or razor pages project. Any way, if you can share your backend code and your Startup.cs, I can directly help you resolve the issue instead of guessing what you did.

Comment: If your project is asp.net core mvc, the url should be:"/ControllerName/ActionName" by default. And no need add token to header.`_pmId` parameter also needs to be added in action

Comment: I tried to use jQuery to loop the modal through in my page. but this not work.

Comment: Hi @Fardin, please share your code instead of saying this not work.