# Find URL submit path of a Razor inherited page controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, inheritance, .net-core, razor

Usually, I send data to a controller with a URL using the class name followed by the method name `/Parent?handler=InitData` or `/Parent/InitData` if the `@page "{handler?}"` is defined in a page.

However, how can this be done with a child controller than inherits the main parent controller ?

What I am looking for is to call a method inside a child controller with a syntax that is similar to this `/Parent/Child/Test`. Note that the call is made within a partial page embedded inside the main parent page.

Any idea on how this can be achieved ? (I know it has something to do with routing but I just don't understand how to do it)

---

Here is what I have so far

Partial page

```
@using App.Models.PagesViews.PartialPage
@model PartialPage // <-- partial parent model has access to PartialPage_Add and PartialPage_Delete children

<script type="module">
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Parent/Child/Test", <-- should call child controller method but is not working!!!

        type: "post",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        ...
    });
</script>

<div>
    <!--... html code...-->
<div>
```

Parent page

```
@page "{handler?}"
@model App.Pages.ParentModel

@section head {
    ...
}

<div>
    <partial name="_PartialPage" model="Model.partialPage_Add"

    ...

    <partial name="_PartialPage" model="Model.partialPage_Delete"
</div>
```

Parent page controller

```
public class ParentModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly DatabaseContext _dbContext;

    public readonly PartialPage_Add partialPage_Add; // <-- PartialPage_Add is a child of PartialPage
    public readonly PartialPage_Delete partialPage_Delete; // <-- PartialPage_Delete is a child of PartialPage

    public MainModel(DatabaseContext _dbContext) 
    {
        this._dbContext = _dbContext;
    }

    public IActionResult OnGet() => Page();
}
```

Child page controller

```
public class ChildModel : ParentModel
{
    public ChildModel(DatabaseContext _dbContext) : base(_dbContext)
    {
    
    }

    public void OnPostTest() // <-- Access this method from partial page
    {
        Log.Debug($"Successfully called method Test() in class ChildModel");

        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#custom-routes  I think you're confusing things when you say child-parent... terminology for extended classes is more like super and sub class.  The sub inherits from the super.  Really has nothing to do with routing since the route will evaluate to a path for a specific .cs file.

Comment: Yes, I realised that a partial page cannot have a custom route and that it needs to use its parent (super) 's controller. I just wanted to avoid having near duplicate code in my super controller by following the DRY principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may misunderstand the usage of Razor Pages and MVC Controller.

Razor Pages should contains `.cshtml` file declared with `@Page` and `.cshtml.cs` file with same name of the `.cshtml` file. Also the `.cshtml.cs` file should inherits *PageModel* or the inheritance class of the *PageModel*.

Your `ChildModel` extends the `ParentModel` which is the inheritance class of `PageModel`, if your project does not contain corresponding `.cshtml`, the `ChildModel` is just **a simple class and cannot be called by ajax**.

So you need be sure your project contains a `Child.cshtml` and declare `@page "{handler?}"` in it. And then the correct url should be `/Child/Test`.

If you want to use the parent as the suffix, change the page route template to `@Page "/Parent/Child/{handler?}"`.

Besides, you must send the **AntiForgeryToken** together with the data you want to the **Post** method if you use ajax in Razor Pages.

Reference:

[How to take result value of a jQuery script into a C# code in the same razor page in ASP.NET Core MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353847/how-to-take-result-value-of-a-jquery-script-into-a-c-sharp-code-in-the-same-razo/70357759#70357759)

For MVC controller, no matter your project contains the `.cshtml` file or not, you can also hit the action, because you can configure the route template in the Startup.cs/Program.cs or just use `[Route]` attribute.